# What causes more gas consumption - Idling with AC or Heat?

Tags: ac, fuel-consumption, idle, gasoline, heater

So I have begun doing some research on the effects of idling. So my question is, does idling with the AC or heater on affect how much gas is given off? If possible, please give the percent of extra gas given off (e.g. AC causes 10% of extra gas to be given off). Thanks for your help!